# Convert jquery touchevent eventListener into vanillaJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm trying to convert some code written with jQuery into vanillaJs but i'm blocked with a touchstart event.
Here's the old code :

```js
var buttonMenu = $('.js-desktop-menu');
buttonMenu.on('click touch', function () {
  if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
    // Something
  } else {
    // Something else
  }
});
```

I've rewrite it like this :

```js
const buttonMenu = document.querySelector('.js-desktop-menu');
const clickEvent = (function() {
  if ('ontouchend' in document.documentElement)
    return 'touchend';
  else
    return 'click';
})

buttonMenu.addEventListener(clickEvent, function(e) {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 992) {
    // Something
  } else {
   // Something else
  }
});
```

But  touchstart event looks like not executed. Did i have doing something wrong ?

Comment: You're missing a pair of parenthesis at the end of `const clickEvent = (function() {...})` it must be `const clickEvent = (function() {...})();`. Also why do you need a function ?

Comment: I have an error in compiled file if i'w writing like this. Code is compiled with gulp. @Rory McCrossan's answer is OK :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the function to return the string for the *type* argument in `addEventListener()`. Right now you're passing the function reference when a string is expected. Try this:

```js
const buttonMenu = document.querySelector('.js-desktop-menu');
const getEventType = () => 'ontouchend' in document.documentElement ? 'touchend' : 'click';

buttonMenu.addEventListener(getEventType(), e => {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 992) {
    // Something
  } else {
    // Something else
  }
});
```

Two things to note here. Firstly I made the function to get the event type a little more succinct with a ternary expression and arrow function, but the logic is the same.

Secondly, you use `querySelector()` implying that only a single element will exist in the DOM with the provided selector, yet you give it a class selector. Be wary that this may cause unexpected behaviour if you ever add multiple `.js-desktop-menu` elements in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was a little thing x). 
I know i have only one element with class "js-desktop-menu", that's why i didn't use `document.querySelectorAll` :).